# jquery mobile web application

Tags: jquery, iphone

i would like to develop iPhone App something similar to [this link](http://colliers.de/iphone_app/en/index.html)

i am planning to develop this using jQuery.

i would like to have some pointers as  how to set database and access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully JQuery mobile comes out on Oct 16th and will have a rich set of controls to accomplish the app you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to develop your app in JQuery then you are talking about a web app rather than a native one.  In this case, you can use HTML 5's new Web SQL Database feature which is implemented in Safari on iPhone.  Search on HTML5 Web SQL Database and you'll find plenty of emerging resources.

If you are writing a native app but using JQuery inside a UIWebView then you can use the iPhone native CoreData library or use a SQLite database (the same DB used by HTML5) and bridge between Javascript and the database.

Whichever solution you go for, it's unlikely that JQuery itself will support what you want to do at this stage because HTML5 databases are not widely implemented, and JQuery won't bridge into Objective-C for you.  You will need to write the support in Javascript yourself, but this should be entirely possible at this point on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap dude. PhoneGap. That's pretty much all you need to say.